# How can I have an ECS Fargate scheduled job access API with an IP address whitelist policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate

I'm trying to set up a scheduled task with ECS Fargate. The task was dockerized and would be run through AWS ECS with Fargate.

Unfortunately, the service I want to run needs to access an API of a partner where the IP address needs to be whitelisted. I see that for each execution of the task with Fargate, a new ENI with an different IP address is assigned.

How is it possible to assign a static IP address to a AWS ECS Fargate task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to assign a *static* IP address on your AWS Fargate task, you will have to create a static IP address (AWS calls this an elastic IP address) that will serve as the origin address of traffic originating your VPC from network outsiders point of view. To implement this:

You need the following:

- A [VPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_cloud)
- 1x private subnet
- 1x public subnet
- 1x Internet gateway attached to the public subnet
- An elastic IP address (will serve as a static IP address of all resources inside the private subnets)
- 1x [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) gateway
- A route table attached to `private` subnet with route `0.0.0.0/0` pointing to the NAT Gateway
- A route table attached to `public` subnet with route `0.0.0.0/0` pointing to the internet gateway

You will then need to make sure that:

- Your ECS Fargate task is using the VPC mentioned above (use `awsvpc` as the network mode, and configure your ECS service to use the private subnet)
- And that the private subnet(s) mentioned above is selected as the `service task placement`

If my explanation is still confusing, you could try giving [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-configure-network.html) a read.

Comment: Thank Allan,  I've already setup a VPC, the subnets, internet and NAT gateway and assigned them to each other but it doesn't work. Can you show me how to place my fargate task on this VPC?

Comment: @H.Dang, this YT video is a good start: https://youtu.be/CZd-VzwL_lg?t=246, Have you provisioned your ECS using CloudFormation? Manually? Terraform?

Comment: @H.Dang make sure you set "Assign Public IP" to `false` on the Fargate task, and make sure you are deploying it only into private subnets that have a route to the NAT gateway.

Comment: @AllanChua Thank you for your support during my recent experience.

Comment: @AllanChua I appreciate your very detailed guidance. It works.